Dynamic generating topology via xml file using omnet++ INET: Channel not initialized error
void NetBuilder::buildNetwork(cModule *parent)
{
    const char* xmlPath = par("xmlConfig");
    cXMLElement* xmlRoot = getEnvir()->getXMLDocument(xmlPath);

    if (xmlRoot == nullptr) {
        EV << "XML file not found or invalid format." << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (cXMLElement* node : xmlRoot->getChildrenByTagName("node")) {
        const char* id = node->getAttribute("id");
        const char* type = node->getAttribute("type");
        cModuleType* moduleType = cModuleType::get(type);
        cModule* nodeModule = moduleType->create(id, parent);
        nodeModule->finalizeParameters();
     }

    for (cXMLElement* link : xmlRoot->getChildrenByTagName("link")) {
        const char* from = link->getAttribute("from");
        const char* to = link->getAttribute("to");
        const char* bandwidth = link->getAttribute("bandwidth");
        const char* delay = link->getAttribute("delay");

        cModule *fromModule = getParentModule()->getSubmodule(from);
        cModule *toModule = getParentModule()->getSubmodule(to);

        cGate *srcIn, *srcOut, *dstIn, *dstOut;

        fromModule->getOrCreateFirstUnconnectedGatePair("ethg", false, true, srcIn, srcOut);
        toModule->getOrCreateFirstUnconnectedGatePair("ethg", false, true, dstIn, dstOut);

        cDatarateChannel *channel1 = cDatarateChannel::create("channel1");
        channel1->setDatarate(atof(bandwidth));
        channel1->setDelay(atof(delay));
        srcOut->connectTo(dstIn, channel1);
  
        cDatarateChannel *channel2 = cDatarateChannel::create("channel2");
        channel2->setDatarate(atof(bandwidth));
        channel2->setDelay(atof(delay));
        dstOut->connectTo(srcIn, channel2);
      }

    cModuleType* configuratorType = cModuleType::get("inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator");
    cModule* configuratorModule = configuratorType->create("configurator", parent);
    configuratorModule->finalizeParameters();

    cModuleType* canvasType = cModuleType::get("inet.visualizer.canvas.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer");
    cModule* canvasModule = canvasType->create("visualizer", parent);
    canvasModule->finalizeParameters();

    parent->callInitialize();
}

The routes are correct generated, but when transmitting,the error is posted:

<!> (omnetpp::cIdealChannel)StaticNet.n1.ipv4.transportIn.channel: Channel not initialized (did you forget to invoke callInitialize() for a dynamically created channel or a dynamically created compound module that contains it?) -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) StaticNet.n1.tn (id=25), at t=0.5s, event #4


Could you edit your question and add [mcve]?
